# Combining matrices to produce one matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, matrix, excel-2013

I have a requirement to build a normalised table of results from three table sets (currently in Excel 2013) as shown here:

[image]

What I would usually do is manually run through each selection to create the normalised sets, but as you can see it's a bit complicated here. The table will be used as a reference to select records from an SQL Server database. What I need to do is make sure that once I loop through this table with T-SQL that each criteria has the required amount the client had selected here, but I can't do this without calculating how many are needed across all three selections, otherwise they won't overlay properly.

What I would like to know is 1. What I should be searching for, to find a solution to this. 2. What is it called when you combine sets and percentiles like this? I don't actually want a solution, as I'd rather do that myself, since I've not made a start on any code or logic I wouldn't expect anyone else to start it for me. I just simply want a point in the right direction as I literally do not know where to start, and it would save me alot of time in the future.

I realised you probably need to see an example end product like this:

[image]

I calculated the first few like so: Newcastle Males: 500, 220 need to be 18-24 which is 22% of the total for that area. And 190 need to be AB Segment, so that's 19% of the total, so to work out the cross examined total for that selection, it would be (500 * .22) * .19 = 21 (rounded off).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, can't help with the formal terms you've asked for but (IMO) for such a small dataset it matters not and brute-force can easily be your friend.

I would suggest [UNPIVOT](http://www.ingenioussql.com/2013/05/09/standard-t-sql-unpivot/)ing each of your 3 datasets to get datasets you can more easily work with `{Gender,Area,Reqs}, {Ageband,Area,Reqs}, {SEG,Area,Req}` and simply apply your calculations to those as 'normal'...

Comment: Pretty much what I ended up doing. Thanks.